# How to handle 300 Multiple Choices Exception for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I have an exception error for testing an API that I am not quite sure how to handle. Here is the snippet of code at the bottom.

```
begin
  open(release_url(uuid)) do |feed|
      response = JSON.parse(feed.read)
      return get_target_releases_json(response['targets']) if feed.status.first != 200
      return if pss.etag == feed.meta['etag']
      response['releases']
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    puts "#---Exception---#"
    puts e
end
```

What is pertinent to understand the problem is the `open(url)` method.

When I reach this point using `byebug` I get an exception that is a `300 - Multiple Choices` error. I read a little bit about it but I don't understand what I need to do to correct this. The api (which is internal to my company btw) is supposed to return a JSON structure when it hits 300. When I place this api url in my browser, I am able to see the JSON payload but when I try to use it programmatically, it errors out. Where does the problem lie? Is it in the api url or could it be elsewhere? As or right now, I can't do anything with this test url call so I'm a little bit stuck. Does anyone have any ideas to discover what I can do with this?

Comment: Can you curl the url from the same server on which this code is running? Does it also return a 300 error? From byebug have you tried to `require 'open-uri'` and then `JSON.load(open(release_url(uuid)))`?

Comment: Hey thanks for the response DaniG2k. So I did try to curl and it works fine. Apparently, using the faraday handles the response error just fine. Although python's urllib, ruby's open-uri, and the rest-client gem failed with that error. So I guess for now, I'll be using faraday.